# WearOS watch that records and sends stepCounts as message via Bluetooth to Phone. The phone app's textview for step update is not syncing instantly

Tags: android, bluetooth, sharedpreferences, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I am trying to debug the slow sync between wearOS watch that records and sends step counts as messages via Bluetooth to its companion Android App? It has a delay when storing it to SharedPreferences and sometimes it doesn't even update until the next message is sent by watch and received by phone. When logging the results received and stored in the app it shows the most up-to-date one, but the view does not refresh to update the UI with the new data that came in.
The steps view needs to be updated with this class. I thought that UI is not being updated even though the step count is being received.

```
public class ActivityRecord extends Activity {
TextView step_count;
TextView sitting_duration,sitting_title;
TextView distance_cover;
TextView walk_value;
ImageView walk, step,distance_covr,sitting;
ImageView maintenence, men_badge;
TextView men_text;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_updated);
    String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("StoreTodayDate", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dateNow=pref.getString("todayDate",null);
    walk=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_walk);
    step=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_step);
    distance_covr=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_distance);
    sitting=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_sit);
    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.progress_walk).into(walk);
    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.progress_step).into(step);
    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.progress_distance).into(distance_covr);
    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.progress_sedentary).into(sitting);
    walk_value=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.walking_val);
    step_count=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.step_count_val);
    sitting_duration=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.sitting_val);
    distance_cover=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance_covered_val);
    step_count.invalidate();
    if(date.equals(dateNow)){
        // setting walk_value
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesForActivityRecord = getSharedPreferences("activity_val",MODE_PRIVATE);
        float testWalk= sharedPreferencesForActivityRecord.getFloat("walk_duration", 0);
        float testStepCount=sharedPreferencesForActivityRecord.getFloat("step_count_value", 0);
        float testSitting=sharedPreferencesForActivityRecord.getFloat("sitting_duration", 0);
        int heartRateToStore=sharedPreferencesForActivityRecord.getInt("heart_rate", 0);
        int Sit_sec = (int) testSitting % 60;
        int Sit_min = (int) ((testSitting / 60));
        Log.d("Phone: "," Walk Value Before Calculation: "+testWalk);
        int Walk_sec = (int)testWalk % 60;
        int Walk_min =(int)(testStepCount/110); //(int)((testWalk / 60));
        // walk value
       // String valueToPutWalk=String.format("%d Min %d Sec",Walk_min,Walk_sec);
        String valueToPutWalk=String.format("%d min",Walk_min);
        if(stepValuetoSet!=0){
            walk_value.setText(valueToPutWalk);
        }else{
            walk_value.setText("0");
        }
        //setting sitting duration;
        String sitting_value=String.format("%d min",Sit_min);
        sitting_duration.setText(sitting_value);

        float in_mile=(float) (testStepCount/2000);
        String dis_in_mile=String.format("%.2f miles",in_mile);
        distance_cover.setText(dis_in_mile);
    }else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = pref.edit();
        editor2.putString("todayDate", date);
        editor2.commit();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor21 = getSharedPreferences("activity_val", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor21.putFloat("walk_duration",0);
        editor21.putFloat("sitting_duration",0);
        editor21.putFloat("step_count_value",0);
        editor21.commit();

        walk_value.setText("0 Min");
        step_count.setText("0");
        sitting_duration.setText("0 Min");
        distance_cover.setText("0 miles");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("set_goal", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putInt("walk_target", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }        
}

public void refreshScreen(View view){
    Intent intent=new Intent(this, ActivityRecord.class);
    intent.putExtra("from","ActivityRecord");
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void timeRemainButtonClicked(View view) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,RemainingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("from","intervention");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```